# "insert into select" with a generator as ID field

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to insert into a table B from a query A that has 5 records using a generator based on the primary ID of Table B, lets call it GEN_B so they don't repeat IDs in tableB.

TableB has (ID, nameB, lastnameB).
Query A (5 records) is the select query here:

```sql
Insert Into TableB (ID, nameB, lastnameB) 
SELECT 
  GEN_ID(GEN_B,1), Name, LastNAme
FROM 
  Table123
  left join .....
  left join.....
where...
```

Why do I only see one record being inserted into TableB when I ran the "Insert into Select...", as opposed to the five records in the select query A? Is it because of the generator not updating the record inserted every time? Will I need to make a execute block for this? If so, any ideas how?

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using? Is `TableB` also involved in the source query? Please provide a [mre] which we can basically copy, paste and execute to reproduce. For your information, in Firebird 4.0, this would work.

Comment: If only one record gets inserted that would suggest your query returns only one record.

Comment: problem is solved, turns out as Ondrej Kelle kind of mentioned it. After the first insert, the query interates again and returns an empty value, hence, no insert. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved, turns out after the first insert, the query interates again and returns an empty value, hence, no insert after the first one.

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using?